# Laravel 6 what does error Action Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ShareReportController not defined means?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Can someone explain what does error

```
(1/1) InvalidArgumentException
Action Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ShareReportController
```

directly mean in `Laravel Framework 6.4.0`?

This shows only in one case, when I want to reset password by default Laravel logic.

Comment: What is the installed laravel and ignition version?

Comment: This shows only in oen case, when I want to reset password by default Laravel logic.

Comment: Laravel Framework 6.4.0

Comment: php artisan route:cache

Comment: I did it it not work

Comment: composer install --no-dev; php artsian cache:clear; php artisan config:clear; php artisan view:clear; php artisan route:clear